# CSS two elements 50% each aligned vertically and horizontally

Tags: css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3X9h/3/)

I have problem in my button. I want my button divided into two, 50% each.

For example in my fiddle, I have a `blue` button having text `Use` and `icon1`

`Use` and `icon1` should be `50%` each and aligned vertically and horizontally relative to the `blue` button which I can't do that for some reasons.

Same goes on red button as well.

Solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3X9h/15/)

```
        <div class='gc_footer_use_nix'>
            <div class='gc_footer_nix'>
                <div class="gc_footer_button_wrapper">                        
                    <div class='gc_footer_nix_txt'>Nix</div>
                    <div class='gc_footer_nix_icon'>icon2</div>                       
                </div>    
            </div>                 
            <div class='gc_footer_use'>
                <div class="gc_footer_button_wrapper">
                    <div class='gc_footer_use_txt'>Use</div>
                    <div class='gc_footer_use_icon'>icon1</div>
                </div>     
            </div>               
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .gc_footter_use_nix{
        text-align: right;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;             
        width: 50%;     


    }

    .gc_footer_use{
        display: table-cell;             
        vertical-align: middle; 
        background-color: #3F6EB6;  
        padding:5px 30px 5px 30px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .gc_footer_use_txt{
        float: left;
        display: table-cell;            
        vertical-align: middle;                 
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;

    }   

    .gc_footer_use_icon{
        text-align: right;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;                 
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;           


    }           

    .gc_footer_nix{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;                 
        background-color: #D61920;
        padding:5px 30px 5px 30px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        float: right;
        border: 0px solid green;

    }

    .gc_footer_nix_txt{
        float: left;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;                 
        position: relative;   
        border: 0px solid blue;
    }   

    .gc_footer_nix_icon{
        float: right;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;                 
        position: relative;
        border: 0px solid yellow;


    }

    .gc_footer_button_wrapper{
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS in the question as well, make sure it contains a repro (having the fiddle only as *support*).

Comment: It's not clear what layout you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Try <del>[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3X9h/4/)</del> [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3X9h/5/).

I changed these rules:

```
.gc_footer_use {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #3F6EB6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.gc_footer_button_wrapper {
    display: table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

.gc_footer_use_txt {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
}

.gc_footer_use_icon{
    text-align: right;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;                 
    padding: 5px 5px 3px 5px;  
}
```

### Explanation

I made the `gc_footer_button_wrapper` class to use the `table` display and be as wide as its parent container `box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;`. Then I made its children to be table-cells that are vertically middle aligned.

I also removed `float` rules from `gc_footer_use_txt` and `gc_footer_use_icon` classes as with my technique it was unnecessary.

Finally, I moved the padding rules to the `gc_footer_button_wrapper`. These paddings can be customized they you see fit. One might even remove them.

You can use the same technique for the other button.

Comment: Thank you. But is it not possible to center the text horizontally 50% each relative to button size? Since it was floated on the left and right only.

Comment: Yes, something like the blue button but it should be same size with `red` and aligned on red button.

Comment: I think this is now okay. Thanks for helping - Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h3X9h/15/